# Git local branch always auto merged with parent(either local or remote) branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Assume `foo` branched out from `master`. Whenever `master` is updated, then those changes must automatically get merged with `foo`. So that no need of using this below command when each time `master` is updated.

```
git merge master
```

Basically looking for a command such as,

```
git checkout -b foo --keep_updated_with_master
```

If this is possible, will it be applicable for local and remote branches?
If not possible, is there any alternatives?

Comment: If both branches are identical, then what's the point of keeping this exact duplicate branch?

Comment: The `foo` branch has some other changes which are not in `master`

Comment: Then if that process is automatic, who will manage merge conflicts? Question doesn't make sense!

Comment: So that is the reason I need a command which makes task simple. For instance whenever I do a commit on `foo`, should try to auto merge `master` and show me the conflicts that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hook.

> What are hooks ?

Well usually they are scripts that can execute whenever a commit or merge happens . Read [here](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for more details.

So you create your hook , write inside what you want to do in script. For instance

```
git merge master
```

**FYI:**

I would not recommend it for the sake of merge conflicts , and other unforseen aspects of auto merging.

Comment: Then, who is going to look into merge conflicts?

Comment: yes you are right... I forgot to mention that i won't recommend this approach but for the sake of providing an alternative i mentioned it now.